# How to use a variable to select a document property?

Tags: javascript

I want to have

```
document.body.innerHTML
```

or

```
document.head.innerHTML
```

I tried the obvious:

```
document.variable.innerHTML
```

but no go.  Also want it to pass jshint.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
document[variable].innerHTML
```

The `.` notation requires the property name to be a valid identifier, and a constant. Object property names, however, can be any string. Thus, whenever you have a property name that's an "ugly" string, or a string held in a variable (or computed by some expression), you use the `[ ]` operator to access it.

Comment: It's perfectly valid JavaScript.